# "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError" with Sikuli + Selenium Java code

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sikuli

I'm trying to learn Sikuli + Selenium integration by following steps mentioned [here](http://romankukla.blogspot.in/2012/11/how-to-use-sikuli-script-with-selenium.html). I followed all steps mentioned till adding jar files to project and wrote following Java code:

```
package sikuliseleniumpackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
import org.sikuli.script.Pattern;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;

public class TestClass {

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws FindFailed 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FindFailed {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        Pattern image = new Pattern("C:\\Images\\google_image.png");

        Screen screen = new Screen();

        screen.wait(image, 10);

    }

}
```

When I executed above code, following error is thrown:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplib\Win32Util.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1928)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1825)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:792)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1059)
at com.wapmx.nativeutils.jniloader.NativeLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLoader.java:44)
at org.sikuli.script.Win32Util.<clinit>(Win32Util.java:19)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:186)
at org.sikuli.script.Env.getOSUtil(Env.java:91)
at org.sikuli.script.ScreenHighlighter.init(ScreenHighlighter.java:180)
at org.sikuli.script.ScreenHighlighter.<init>(ScreenHighlighter.java:293)
at org.sikuli.script.Screen.initBounds(Screen.java:105)
at org.sikuli.script.Screen.<init>(Screen.java:117)
at sikuliseleniumpackage.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:22)
```

Please help me how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly you **have** to use a 32-Bit JDK\JRE to run Sikuli even if you have a 64-Bit machine.

Even your Error-Message says that:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplib\Win32Util.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform`

Try it with a 32-Bit JDK\JRE.